# Npm error is not resolved. Error is occurring while running depandancies

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, yarnpkg, mern, npm-start

After cloning a MERN Stack Project. I had deleted Node Modules, Package-lock.json. Then i run npm i -timeout=999.After installation, I run command npm start then saw these errors.

**PS

```
C:\Users\Ali\Downloads\pizza-shop-mern-stack-app-cmplete-code-main\pizza-shop-mern-stack-app-cmplete-code-main\client> npm start

> client@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:43:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

**

Comment: i have package.json instead of node modules @cmgchess

Comment: package.json alone is not enough. for example the React library code is saved inside the node modules but the package.json only has the name and version of React

Comment: nodemodules are ignored by creator of code. but i cloned many projects never saw these errors every time i removed package.json and nodemules. when we run command npm install it will automatically create a new folder of node_modules. @cmgchess

Comment: okay i am trying with nodemodules and will get back soon @cmgchess

Comment: do you have react in your package.json dependencies section

Comment: Check Package.json file and try add 'react' or run 'npm install react'. then you have to install all the other packages in pacakge.json by simply 'npm install'

Comment: @MuhammadBilal i am runinng npm install

Comment: Waiting for your Response

Comment: Not installing all DEPANDANCIES@MuhammadBilal